# Short story where all hard surfaces are destroyed by the droppings of an alien bird

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, post-apocalyptic

I read a short story many years ago with a twist-ending similar to Ray Bradbury stories.

Tthe story was post-apocalyptic and the ending involved a strange alien birdlike creature that poos on the road tarmac and a plant begins to grow that cracks and destroys the road.
The implication being that the bird's presence has led to the end of the world as we know it because all concrete, etc has been destroyed.

I was reading a lot of Bradbury and Allen Dean Foster at the time so it could have been them but I have never come across the story again despite searching every few years.

Comment: is it me or does that sound like nibblers planet from futurama (I know its not but still..)

Comment: Reminds me of the old Foo Bird joke...

Comment: How much can one bird poop that leaves the the entire world destroyed? There is 4.09 million miles of road in the US alone (.25 million is highways and interstates, not to mention airplanes and boat ways). I feel sorry for all the statues.

Comment: It sounds like the sort of thing Christopher Anvil's human colonists have to cope with on his alien planets - some seemingly inimical ecological feature or other. But you say that it's on Earth? Was the bird imported from another world or created? A species created to destroy technological civilization features in "Doctor Zombie And His Furry Little Friends" by Sheckley, so it's in his wheelhouse.